# XLS markup to XLSX conversion

Tags: c#, excel, xlsx

I have recently inherited some C# code that creates XLS files manually using XML and XSLT. I need to update the code to write XLSX files instead of XLS files (in order to take advantage of the increased column and row count). Is there any simple method for creating an XLSX document programmatically and then injecting it with the raw XML?

Here is the code that transforms and saves the file.

```
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(sourceXML));
        XmlDataDocument xdd = new XmlDataDocument();
        xdd.Load(reader);

        XslCompiledTransform xct = new XslCompiledTransform();

        XmlReader xsltdatareader;
        xsltdatareader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xsldata));
        xct.Load(xsltdatareader);

        try
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(resultXlsFilename);
            xct.Transform(xdd, null, sw);
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close(); 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have code that create HTML code which can be opened with Ms Excel. That file structure is very simpler than XLSX (Office Open XML).

It´s very hard to write code for convert XLS in XLSX. Anyway a XLSX file is actually a renamed zip file, with some XMLs inside. Even you can write your XLSX manually, you can try to use the s api:

Open XML SDK:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5124

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Aspose.Cells for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx) to create XLSX files. This is a normal .NET assembly. It doesn't require MS Office to be installed on the machine your application is working on. You can use it with any type of .NET application on any Windows OS. You can also [work with data](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/working-with-data.html) in different ways and [import data into XSLX file from various sources](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/importing-data-to-worksheets.html). Please see if this helps in your scenario.

Disclosure: I work as developer evangelist at Aspose.